# ionic otp verification issue not recognising the otp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

otp is not identifying. otp is showing as invalid credentials. I am using ionic alertcontroller to getting otp. backend is not identifying the otp. it is showing as undefined in backend and error response. How to resolve this. Is there any way to use ngModel binding in alert controller.

html

```html
<div class="floating-label">
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" id="email" name="Email" [(ngModel)]="Email">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="floating-label">
        <input placeholder="Mobile" type="Mobile" id="mobileno" name="Mobile" [(ngModel)]="Mobile">
        <label for="email">Mobile</label>
        <div class="btn-sec">
            <button type="submit" (click)="Continue(Mobile,Email)">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```js
    async Continue(Mobile, Email) {

        const user = {
            Mobile: Mobile,
            Email: Email,
        }
        console.log(Mobile);
        console.log(Email);
        this.api.SignupUser(user).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        this.alert1 = await this.alertCtrl.create({
                header: 'OTP',
                message: 'Please Enter your Otp sent to your Mobile Number',

                inputs: [{
                    name: 'otp',
                    value: 'otp'


                }],
                buttons: [{
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        role: 'cancel'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'ConfirmOTP',
                        handler: () => {
                            var user1 = {
                                Mobile: this.Mobile,
                                Email: this.Email,
                                otp: this.otp
                            };
                            console.log(user1);
                            this.api.Verifyotp(user1).subscribe(data => {
                                console.log(data);
                                this.data = data;
                                if (this.data.Msg) {
                                    alert(this.data.Msg);
                                } else {
                                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    ]
                }); this.alert1.present();
        };
```

service.ts

```js
SignupUser(user): Observable <Object> {
    console.log(user);

    console.log('getting the signup data from user');
    return this.http.post < Object > (`${this.base_url}/signup`, user);

}
Verifyotp(user): Observable <Object> {
    console.log(user);
    console.log('getting all Listing from the server');
    return this.http.post < Object > (`${this.base_url}/verifysignupotp`, user);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried adding type: 'number' in input in alert property? it could be type cast issue. It would be great if you add the console log output also.

Comment: I tried .But not working

Comment: What value are you getting from this "console.log(user1);"?